# How to apply FreezePanes in multiple sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code below, but i don't know how to fit it for several sheets.

```
Set r = ActiveCell
 Range("A4").Select
 With ActiveWindow
 .FreezePanes = False
 .ScrollRow = 1
 .ScrollColumn = 1
 .FreezePanes = True
 .ScrollRow = r.Row
End With
r.Select
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to add `FreezePanes` for all sheets, you can add following code to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Range("A4").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .FreezePanes = False
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
End Sub
```

or you can specify sheets like follows (next code will add `FreezePanes` only for sheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Or Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then
        Range("A4").Select
        With ActiveWindow
           .FreezePanes = False
           .FreezePanes = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :) One tip though. You need to issue `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False` before you set it to true because if panes are already frozen in that sheet, say at A20 then the above will not reset it to A4.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thank you for teachung me!:) I'll update my answer

Comment: Not teaching you anything :) BTW don't just trust what I say... Test it yourself first ;)

Comment: I've said it in complementary way:) and I've tested it before updating:)

Comment: Complementary means something different from complimentary.